# Exclude single executable from PATH, without chmod -x it

Tags: bash, path

I'm trying to remove a single executable from $PATH, without modifying it

e.g I have `/Users/USER/Library/Python/2.7/bin/` in `$PATH`, and I'd like to exclude `services.py` from that directory.

I know `chmod -x services.py` will work, but I'm trying to find a better way

Is it possible?

Comment: alias services.py=':'

Comment: @RakeshSharma Hmm, what does `:` do in bash?

Comment: `:`is a sort of `NOP` in assembly.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Oh I get it

Answer (score 4):

If you can move the file to a sub-directory that will avoid its execution.
If you can not, there are some workarounds:

You can add something of a higher priority so that it executes before the executable you are trying to avoid.

## New dir in PATH.

You can create an executable at a higher level in the PATH order.

If `$PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, an (empty?) executable at `/usr/bin` will be executed at a higher priority than an executable at `/bin`.

In this direction, you can add a path at the start of `$PATH` to ensure that the new executable is executed before (in replacement of) `services.py`

Note that some shells remember executed path of programs. In bash that is controlled by the command `hash` (a hash -r will remove all hashed programs). A new bash shell has no hashed programs, except those executed in the starting files (usually `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.profile`). So, a new shell which has the new `PATH` in effect at the start will work.

If you can not change the PATH, or move the file, you can you can use a function or alias definition in `~/.bashrc`, or some other start up file like `~/.profile`.

Functions and aliases have higher precedence than executables, so, naming a function (or alias) like the executable will effectively replace it in shells that have such function defined.

## function

Something as simple as this will do:

```
services.py(){ :; } # do nothing
```

To test, you may set `ls` to nothing:

```
ls(){ :; }
```

A function could be erased with `unset -f FunctionName`.

```
 $ unset -f ls
```

To remove the `ls` function.

Note that a function is not perfect, the original executable could be called with the full path:

```
$ /bin/ls
listOfFiles
…
```

A function will prevent just "this shell" from executing the program. Any other shell (or program that could call `execve` by itself) will run the executable.

## alias

An alias is less powerful, it only replace the first word of a simple command.
And if the command has some form of quoting, it will avoid the alias.

```
$ alias ls='echo "none"'
$ ls
none
$ \ls
ListOfFiles
…
```

An alias could be erased with `unalias AliasName`. So, this:

```
 $ unalias ls
```

Will remove the alias definition of `ls`.

The most robust method to change the PATH. Either by pre-pending a new dir or by moving the file to a new directory. Include such directory in the `$PATH` only for those instances that will be allowed to execute the program.

Comment: Could also add an empty shell script to a higher priority directory in `$PATH`.