# Remove executable from path

Tags: bash, path, autocomplete

I have a script called `teleport` in my path. When I type `tele` and hit tab, I'd like for tab-completion to complete this to `teleport`.

However, there's another program installed on my system: `telepathy-gabble-xmpp-console` This starts with the same letters, so tab completion only gets up to `telep`.

If this were my system, I would just remove that one executable to improve my workflow. However, this is a shared server. (Accounts are not shared.)

Alternately, I could change my `$PATH` to exclude it. However, `telepathy-gabble-xmpp-console` is in `/bin`, and obviously I can't just remove `/bin` from my path.

The solutions described in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350905/exclude-single-executable-from-path-without-chmod-x-it) don't work, because defining a function or alias will still autocomplete to that function or alias.

How do I take a single executable out of my `$PATH`?

(Yes, I realize that this is a lot of work for a small benefit.)

Comment: Another option could be to just alias `tele` to `teleport`, and then you don't even need to hit tab.

Comment: Related: [Hide some commands from bash completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314631/hide-some-commands-from-bash-completion)

Comment: Per Mark's comment above, do you have bash v4.4?

Comment: I have `bash, version 4.4.23(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I added this line to .bashrc:

```
export EXECIGNORE=*/telepathy-gabble-xmpp-console
```

This approach did not work:

```
export EXECIGNORE=$(which telepathy-gabble-xmpp-console)
```

Because `telepathy-gabble-xmpp-console` is installed in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

A slight modification works, though, using `which -a`:

```
export EXECIGNORE=$(which -a telepathy-gabble-xmpp-console | tr '\n' ':' | head -c -1)
```